# Tips in finding out best way to compare and sort multi level arrays

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

So I am a programmer who is pretty ok with the regular decision tree based algorithms and even with optimizations related to making small enhancements by skipping an extra step in calculation or even tweaking queries a bit to make our apps faster.

I am facing a problem that is a bit more algorithmically complex to solve than I am used to. The idea is that I will have this **data array** of say, a thousand elements. Each element of the data array is an array of its own with an additional 5-10 elements.

I will another **value array** for which I have to find the best matching ten array element nodes from the first and return in the best matching sequence.

Some sample data to visualize:

say the value array looks so:

```
$arr = array(
  elm1 = 0.125,
  elm2 = 5
  elm3 = 200
);
```

and the data array will look something like:

```
$array = array(
   [0] => array(elm1 => 1.5, elm2 => 8, elm3 => 10),
   [1] => array(elm1 => 0.5, elm2 => 4, elm3 => 100),
   ...etc..
);
```

Now the idea is that for each element [elm1, elm2, elm3 etc]  I will give a weightage based on how close the values are for that element in the `value array` and in each of the `data array nodes` then based on that I need to extract the ten best matching data array node elements.

This looks fine in theory, but I am worried about the processing time because users would wait for this in real time. Now I am not a big math guy, even though I have tried to understand the `big(O)`, `n(p)` stuff, it flies over my head.

So I am looking at a more layman-programmer solution rather than going deep into how algorithm complexity works..I am thinking if I created different arrays where the indexes were say elm1, elm2 etc, and then perhaps sort each of those array and run a quick sort it might help. I was curious to know how anyone in this community would tackle an issue like this.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I am not a PHP guy.

In general, or from algorithmic perspective the best solution would be to keep the data you have in bi-dimensional array in a sorted map collection. 
I was able to find [this](https://github.com/chdemko/php-sorted-collections/blob/master/src/SortedCollection/TreeMap.php) implementation of SortedMap in PHP. After you insert all your data there, searching for a matching element from you second array there would be a logarithmic or O(log n) .

Hope this helps...

Comment: I know the question doest not have specific code induced problem and I understand me getting a -1 for it. However I think you for taking the time to answer and am upvoting your answer so you do not suffer a -1 because of it.

Comment: Just for the record: I was not the downvoter. Anonymous downvoters should burn in HELL! Here is a + from me to fix it because the question is not bad IMO

Comment: I would not think you were the downvoter, considering that your answer had a downvote as well. I guess we were both hit and run by the same guy :)